# Python different regex operation treat unicode char differently

Tags: python, regex

```
line = u'in belgi\xeb.'
re.findall('\w+', line, re.UNICODE)
#result: [u'in', u'belgi\xeb']
re.sub('\w+', 'x', line, re.UNICODE)
#result: u'x x\xeb.'
```

`u'\xeb'` is `u'ë'` in case you are interested.

So it seems that findall treats ë as \w but sub not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the [`flags`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.flags) for it :

```
>>> re.sub(r'\w+','x', line, flags=re.UNICODE)
u'x x.'
```

Note that in [`re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) function the fourth argument is `count`!

Comment: That stuff makes me miss strong typing.

Comment: First i was confused but then i just review the `sub` function !

Comment: yeah it didn't came to my head to check actual signature

Answer (score 1):

Ah, figured out myself. The difference it signatures:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

so third param is not always `flags`. Solution is very simple:

`re.sub('\w+', 'x', line, flags=re.UNICODE)`